# Why should I indicate the Option parameter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a Setter() and found code which uses the Option parameter for newValue. 
Should this be interpreted similar to [optional parameter] in brackets? Can it also be left out entirely?

```
class SomeState with ChangeNotifier {
    int _progress = 0;
    Option _selected;

    final PageController controller = PageController();

    get progress => _progress;
    get selected => _selected;

    set progress(double newValue) {
        _progress = newValue;
        notifyListeners();
  }

  set selected(Option newValue) { //here
      _selected = newValue;
      notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question clearly.

**1. Required parameter**

```
// here you need to provide Option
set selected(Option newValue) { 
  _selected = newValue;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

You'd use it like

```
selected(value);
```

---

**2. Positional parameter**

```
// here Option is optional
set selected([Option newValue]) { 
  _selected = newValue;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

You'd use it like

```
selected(value); // if you need to provide value
selected(); // if you don't want to provide any value
```

---

**3. Named parameter**

```
// here Option is optional 
set selected({Option newValue}) { 
  _selected = newValue;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

You'd use it like

```
selected(value: value); // if you want to provide value
selected(); // if you don't to provide value
```

---

**Note:**

Positional and Named parameters can also be be made required, if you use `@required` in front of variable.

If you want to give optional parameter any default value, you can use following in parameters

```
set selected({Option newValue = const SomeValue()}) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, it is not a way to make the value optional. Does that mean that Option is the 'type' of the value 'newValue'?

Comment: You can make it optional using Positional and Named parameter as I showed in above example. And yes the `newValue` is the type of `Option` as you used in your code.